# Expo build 'JavaScript heap out of memory'

Tags: node.js, amd-processor, expo

I have an [Expo](https://github.com/expo/expo) app that I am trying to build.

The build command I use is `expo build:android`.

It fails with an error:

> JavaScript heap out of memory

I added the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable.

[image]

I tried `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` without any effect.

#### File *Package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 && expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
},
```

I am using the latest versions of Node.js NPM and *expo-cli*.

#### Expo diagnostics

```
Expo CLI 4.1.0 environment info:
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
Binaries:
  Node: 15.6.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  npm: 7.4.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
npmPackages:
  expo: ^39.0.5 => 39.0.5
  react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.0.tar.gz => 0.63.2
  react-native-web: ^0.13.18 => 0.13.18
  react-navigation: ^4.4.3 => 4.4.3
Expo Workflow: managed
```

#### *.env* file

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: 'expo upgrade' seems to help. Now using expo SDK 40

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even realize I was still on 37 :) and keeping my memeory settings at 4gigs was enough. Just a note to everyone else seeing this, it may take a long time and seem to hang but keep waiting. After it's done building it will give you a note and then start downloading it to the phone.